# Pandas groupby and transform based on multiple columns

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, group-by, transform

I have seen a lot of similar questions but none seem to work for my case. I'm pretty sure this is just a groupby transform but I keep getting `KeyError` along with `axis` issues. I am trying to groupby `filename` and check count where `pred != gt`.

For example Index 2 is the only one for `f1.wav` so 1, and Index (13,14,18) for `f2.wav` so 3.

```
df = pd.DataFrame([{'pred': 0, 'gt': 0, 'filename': 'f1.wav'}, {'pred': 0, 'gt': 0, 'filename': 'f1.wav'}, {'pred': 2, 'gt': 0, 'filename': 'f1.wav'}, {'pred': 0, 'gt': 0, 'filename': 'f1.wav'}, {'pred': 0, 'gt': 0, 'filename': 'f1.wav'}, {'pred': 0, 'gt': 0, 'filename': 'f1.wav'}, {'pred': 0, 'gt': 0, 'filename': 'f1.wav'}, {'pred': 0, 'gt': 0, 'filename': 'f1.wav'}, {'pred': 0, 'gt': 0, 'filename': 'f1.wav'}, {'pred': 0, 'gt': 0, 'filename': 'f1.wav'}, {'pred': 0, 'gt': 0, 'filename': 'f2.wav'}, {'pred': 0, 'gt': 0, 'filename': 'f2.wav'}, {'pred': 2, 'gt': 2, 'filename': 'f2.wav'}, {'pred': 0, 'gt': 2, 'filename': 'f2.wav'}, {'pred': 0, 'gt': 2, 'filename': 'f2.wav'}, {'pred': 0, 'gt': 0, 'filename': 'f2.wav'}, {'pred': 0, 'gt': 0, 'filename': 'f2.wav'}, {'pred': 2, 'gt': 2, 'filename': 'f2.wav'}, {'pred': 0, 'gt': 2, 'filename': 'f2.wav'}, {'pred': 2, 'gt': 0, 'filename': 'f2.wav'}])
```

```
    pred  gt filename
0      0   0   f1.wav
1      0   0   f1.wav
2      2   0   f1.wav
3      0   0   f1.wav
4      0   0   f1.wav
5      0   0   f1.wav
6      0   0   f1.wav
7      0   0   f1.wav
8      0   0   f1.wav
9      0   0   f1.wav
10     0   0   f2.wav
```

Expected output

```
    pred  gt filename  counts
0      0   0   f1.wav       1
1      0   0   f1.wav       1
2      2   0   f1.wav       1
3      0   0   f1.wav       1
4      0   0   f1.wav       1
5      0   0   f1.wav       1
6      0   0   f1.wav       1
7      0   0   f1.wav       1
8      0   0   f1.wav       1
9      0   0   f1.wav       1
10     0   0   f2.wav       3
11     0   0   f2.wav       3
12     2   2   f2.wav       3
13     0   2   f2.wav       3
14     0   2   f2.wav       3
15     0   0   f2.wav       3
16     0   0   f2.wav       3
17     2   2   f2.wav       3
18     0   2   f2.wav       3
19     2   0   f2.wav       3
```

I was thinking
`df.groupby('filename').transform(lambda x: x['pred'].ne(x['gt']).sum(), axis=1)`
but I get `TypeError: Transform function invalid for data types`

Answer (score 7, accepted):

`.transform` operates on each column individually, so you won't be able to access both 'pred' and 'gt' in a transform operation.

This leaves you with 2 options:

1. aggregate and reindex or join back to the original shape
2. pre-compute the boolean array and `.transform` on that

approach 2 will probably be the fastest here:

```py
df['counts'] = (
    (df['pred'] != df['gt'])
    .groupby(df['filename']).transform('sum')
)

print(df)
    pred  gt filename  counts
0      0   0   f1.wav       1
1      0   0   f1.wav       1
2      2   0   f1.wav       1
3      0   0   f1.wav       1
4      0   0   f1.wav       1
5      0   0   f1.wav       1
6      0   0   f1.wav       1
7      0   0   f1.wav       1
8      0   0   f1.wav       1
9      0   0   f1.wav       1
10     0   0   f2.wav       4
11     0   0   f2.wav       4
12     2   2   f2.wav       4
13     0   2   f2.wav       4
14     0   2   f2.wav       4
15     0   0   f2.wav       4
16     0   0   f2.wav       4
17     2   2   f2.wav       4
18     0   2   f2.wav       4
19     2   0   f2.wav       4
```

Note that `f2.wav` has 4 instances where 'pre' != 'gt' (index 13, 14, 18, 19)

Comment: You can use `.ne` so you can chain: `df['pred'].ne(df['gt']).groupby(...).transform()`.

Comment: Ahh yes this worked, thank you. I rarely use `groupby` as a second operation

Comment: It's a funny pattern to look at, but makes sense if you want to group a column by some external Series. Otherwise we'd need to add the boolean Series as a column to our DataFrame- though its not the end of the world if you do :)

Answer (score 1):

Considering that `df` is the dataframe OP shares in the question, in order to groupby `filename` and check count where `pred` `!=` `gt`, one can use [`pandas.DataFrame.groupby`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.groupby.html) and
[`pandas.DataFrame.apply`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.apply.html) as follows

```
df2 = df.groupby('filename').apply(lambda x: x[x['pred'] != x['gt']])

[Out]:
             pred  gt filename
filename                      
f1.wav   2      2   0   f1.wav
f2.wav   13     0   2   f2.wav
         14     0   2   f2.wav
         18     0   2   f2.wav
         19     2   0   f2.wav
```

Assuming one wants to count the number of occurrences for each `filename`, as, after the previous operation, `filename` is both an index level and a column label, which is ambiguous, and considering that OP [wants to have a column named `count`](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/73708230/pandas-groupby-and-transform-based-on-multiple-columns/73708312#comment130158287_73708312) to count the number of each item in each group, one will have to [`groupby`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.groupby.html) level (one of the various parameters one can pass), and, finally, use [`pandas.core.groupby.GroupBy.cumcount`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.core.groupby.GroupBy.cumcount.html).  (Note: As opposed to the [accepted answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/73708309/7109869), this approach will count sequentially)

```
df2['count'] = df2.groupby(level=0).cumcount() + 1 # The +1 is to make the count start at 1 instead of 0.

[Out]:
             pred  gt filename  count
filename                             
f1.wav   2      2   0   f1.wav      1
f2.wav   13     0   2   f2.wav      1
         14     0   2   f2.wav      2
         18     0   2   f2.wav      3
         19     2   0   f2.wav      4
```

A one-liner would look like the following

```
df2['count'] = df.groupby('filename').apply(lambda x: x[x['pred'] != x['gt']]).groupby(level=0).cumcount() + 1

[Out]:
             pred  gt filename  count
filename                             
f1.wav   2      2   0   f1.wav      1
f2.wav   13     0   2   f2.wav      1
         14     0   2   f2.wav      2
         18     0   2   f2.wav      3
         19     2   0   f2.wav      4
```

If having the count in a separate column is not a requirement, considering `df2` as the dataframe after the first operation mentioned in this answer (when `df2` was created), then one can simply use the following (which gives a more high-level overview)

```
df3 = df2.groupby(level=0).count().iloc[:, 0]

[Out]:
filename
f1.wav    1
f2.wav    4
Name: pred, dtype: int64
```